# Generate n sets of random numbers without a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

so when I generate 1000 sets of random numbers (0..2000) in Python, I can easily do something like this:

```
iters = 1000
randIdx = []
numbers = range(0, 2000)
for i in range(iters):
        randIdx.append(random.sample(numbers, 8))
```

The problem is that the code is VERY slow. Is there a way to avoid the for loop to tell the function to just put out 1000 sets or is there some kind of workaround?
I thought of just generating 8000 random numbers but the problem occurs that it is not possible to do that when in a set of 8 numbers duplicates aren't allowed!

Example:

```
 randIdx=[]
 indexRange = range(0, 3)  
 for i in range(5):
     randIdx.append(random.sample(indexRange, 2))

[[0, 1], [2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 0], [2, 1]]
```

Comment: Your current code raises an exception, can you show an example of the desired output for smaller inputs? e.g. `range(5)` and `numbers = 3`

Comment: sorry, just changed the range from iters to numbers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `numpy` library for this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 2000, (1000, 8))

# array([[1026,   46, 1620, ...,  534, 1098, 1406],
#        [1081, 1235,  484, ..., 1124,  841,    4],
#        [1189, 1505, 1943, ...,   55, 1547, 1936],
#        ..., 
#        [1242,  877, 1129, ...,  230, 1226, 1399],
#        [1134,  939,  969, ..., 1600,  288, 1479],
#        [ 492,    5,  545, ..., 1093, 1805, 1404]])
```

Then just slice the array for one selection, e.g. `arr[0]` will give you the first row as an array.